# elasticsearch -- is there a way to INCREASE the number of results returned?

Tags: elasticsearch, limit, resultset

Every question I see on the size of the result set is focused on *lowering* the number returned.  I have a slightly different issue.  I want to see *more*.

I've got a database of SNMP events.   When I query for events from a certain site by IP, I get a result set of ten items, although the hits field on the result indicates that there are 27.   In particular I am interested in events within the 12:24 minute mark.  The ten results indicate one from 12:24, and the one before that is from 11:47, and the previous ones are even earlier.

I finally got the information I wanted by forcing a boolean query that included both the IP address AND the time range (gte 12:20 lte 12:30) ... and there were three records in that time frame (actually they were all in the 12:24 minute).  BUT ... it would have been so much easier if I could have just scanned the complete result set from the original query.  Why is it taking it upon itself, not just to limit the result set, but the *way* it limited the result set (i.e. one record per timestamp)?

I do not want data silently dropped from my query.   If I get too much, I will filter it down on my own.  How do I make elasticsearch return all 27 records when it is telling me there are 27 hits?  (Yes, I am aware that this is the opposite of most of the questions about the size of the result sets.)

Comment: Elasticsearch returns up to 10000 hits by default. can you share your query and the results response you are getting?

Comment: I can share the query.  I would have to redact the results to make sure we have no identifying or proprietary information in the them.

Comment: Although the "size" parameter mentioned below may do the job I need.  I will check that out first.

Comment: ... then again, a mere size shouldn't be responsible for _how_ the top ten were picked.  That is all from different timestamps, even when there are usually multiple records with similar (i.e. within the same minute) timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the size value in your ES query.

Here's a reference to [ES doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html).

But as Mark mentioned in his comment, using this you won't be able to do deep pagination, getting results set of size > 10000. Though I think this isn't the case for you since you only need to address 27 search results.